# Python program is slow on another computer

Tags: performance

i wrote a program using Wxpython-32 bit-3-3-5.0 (a standalone python distrib)
The problem is that the program is running very well on my computer.
But when used on another computer it can be very slow.
This is a real-time communication software with an embedded system.

Both computer run Windows 8.1 x64 with the same hardware (i5, 4go ram), i also tried with an Arch-linux, i got the same problem.

What could be the problem ? how can i try to solve it ?

Thank's !

Comment: You say it's "real-time communication software", so could network conditions be having an impact? To gain an understanding of what the problem actually is, you'll need to examine what is taking up time when running on computer A vs. computer B -- perhaps using a profiling system ([see this question for some tips on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script))

Comment: Maybe i misspoke. When i say real-time this is with a serial communication,  no network connection.
To profile my software is it a good way to use a decorator with time.time() before and after my method then check the differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cProfile to know what do you need to optimize. 
If using PyQt signals or a signal system for your real time communication, it can slow down the program